# Calling Firebase Event Listeners in onCreate of Fragment

Tags: android, performance, firebase

So, I was reading this [post](https://firebase.googleblog.com/2017/12/using-android-architecture-components.html) from the firebase blog and something caught my eye. They mentions adding the event listeners in onStart(). Typically I add my listeners in onCreate(), so that when the information needs to be shown when onResume is called it'll definitely be there (or atleast it should). Is there any perceivable difference between adding an event listener in onCreate() versus adding one in onStart()? How would I test to see which one is better?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html

Comment: @PeterHaddad so, I read that article before I wrote the question. What I'm really trying to figure out is why the "best practices" are the "best practices". I want to know what happens when we make the http request before way before the UI shows. Does it make a difference? If so, why? Far as I'm concerned, downloading all the relevant data a little earlier shouldn't make a big difference. Unless of course the only reason we download data right before the UI shows is because that insures the data is up to date and decreases the likelihood that additional requests be made before the view shows.

Comment: @PeterHaddad, do you know of a site that shows why the best practices are what they are. Some are easy to understand, but others...aren't. I can't seem to find the answer to "why" on the android developer website. Also, how would I figure if calling an event listener in onCreate makes a big difference? What should be my criteria to determine what's best and by how much?

Answer (score 2):

Don't use onCreate/onDelete, unless you want your listeners to still be listening when the user leaves your app by using the home button, costing you money and user users data.  onStart/onStop defines the visible time of your activity, which is why it's conventional to use those for things that actively put stuff on screen.

onStart is called before onResume when the activity is becoming visible.  Not sure why that would be any better than onCreate if you're concerned about the timing on onResume.  BTW you can't guarantee that data will be available any any point.  It's dependent on the speed and latency of the device's network connection.